# How to recover .pem file if the password has been forgotten

Tags: ios

I am using .pem file on server for push-notification.

Unfortunately I forgot the .pem file password, also my mac is not working so I am not able to create a new PEM file.

I have backup of the .pem file in Dropbox but I'm not able to use that .pem file in my new mac.

Please tell me how check push-notification without changing .pem file on server.

Is there any option so that I can use same  PEM file for push-notification without any change on server as my application is live.

Comment: Maybe someone has a sneaky hack for this, but I think the whole point of the password is that the PEM doesn't work without it. I think you'll have to generate a new one and redeploy your app. I'd also suggest writing down your crypto passwords somewhere safe, as memory is a fickle thing. Also if you work in a team you need to make sure the right people have access in an emergency

Comment: hi richard so if i revoke my certificate and redeploy .pem file on server then will it effect push-notification of my live application ?

Comment: I don't think your users would need to reinstall. You'd just need to get a new certificate from Apple and install it on your server. I typically strip the password off the key before sending off the certificate signing request, as certificates that require a password mean that ops people need the password to hand in order to restart httpd/nginx processes

Answer (score 6):

You've got two choices:

- create a new certificate
- try every possible password until you guess the right one. This could take a few hundred trillion years.

Next time, keep a copy and backup copy of the password.